# Roboearth detector not detecting the coke_bottle

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have tested the roboearth detector with coke bottle and it seems to be not performing well. I am not able see any indication that the detection is done. Am i missing something here.
I have downloaded the coke_bottle dataset from the roboearth database through online and tested it. Following is the sequence of steps i did.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zm2rXDlpg4U&feature=youtu.be

I have posted this issue on roboearth mailing list as well. Posting it here as the response here is very high.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12558/roboearth-detector-not-detecting-the-coke_bottle/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2012-01-08**:
Hi Karthik, have you taken a look at the point clouds the kinect is giving you for the bottle? From my experience the kinect doesnt play too well with transparent materials and gives somewhat unreliable results. Maybe have a try with a solid, non transparent object first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ben_S is right. Our 2D-feature based recognition algorithm will have problems with reflections appearing on the surface of glossy objects such as the coke bottle.

Also, I did not see that you enabled the 'depth_registered' flag for the openni driver. See http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch#Quick_start on how to do that.

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1